# How to update a table while using it at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Local DB (I'm using SQL Server Express) named `PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS`. I need to load data from the main database at `MAINDB\HYEAH`, so I linked the mainDB and I was able to insert data from the main DB into local DB using a stored procedure.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out the correct way to do the following:

I'm constantly using the data imported from the mainDB, that data is in the table `Credits`, I'm always consulting, inserting or updating a record from that table.

But every 10 minutes I have to reload the data from the mainDB into `Credits` again, but I can't stop using the data. I need to find a way to be able to use this data and manipulate it, while is being reloaded from the mainDB.

I'm not an expert in DB or SQL transactions so I thought about this solution:

The first time I load the data from mainDB I'll do it directly on table `Credits`. The other times I'll load the data in a temporary table and when the stored procedure finishes, I'll replace `Credits` with data from the temporary table. But I think this is dumb cause if I delete all the data from `Credits` to replace it with temporary table I will not be able to continue using the data so I'm stuck.

Is there a way to properly achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the question for me is why do you have to constantly drop all the data and reload it? That sounds like the problem to me.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to re-invent [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication); consider using that instead. Express can't be a publisher for replication, but it can be a subscriber, which sounds like it would be enough for your scenario.

Comment: Agree with Sean - I'd look at adding a `Processed` flag on your source table so your import process knows what rows it can skip. Alternatively, if the rows can be updated, add a `LastModifiedDate` column and record the last time the import process ran.

Comment: @SeanLange the data from table Credits needs to be always updated, and because Idk much about SQL I thought in deleting all the Credits table from Local DB and inserting data from stored procedure again. Maybe I can compare the data result from the SP against Credits and update Credits only in the rows needed? but what can I do if a row no longer exists in mainDB

Comment: @JeroenMostertthis is very interesting I'm taking a look. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sounds more and more like replication.

Comment: @amcdermott I think my problem is the SP. this SP retrieves information from many tables in the mainDB and return them. Initially, I stored the data from this SP into a .dat file, then, I consulted this file when needed, deleting it and restoring at certain time. I will consider your suggestion as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use synonyms.

```
BEGIN TRY
    DROP SYNONYM working_table
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

CREATE SYNONYM working_table FOR import_table_a
```

you can now do your selects and updates to working_table and they will go into import_table_a.  When you need to reload the data (into import_table_b) you just drop the synonym and point it at the new version of the table.

But do take on board the other comments that imply that you might be fixing the wrong problem :)

Comment: Aaron thanks for the answer, I'll try to implement it and let you know! :)

Comment: So I was able to use this solution, and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)